# Get all the action log of an instance and the flavor attached to it

Tags: openstack, novaclient, openstacksdk

I was wondering if anyone can tell me how to get the action log of the instance using openstacksdk, novaclient. And while getting the action log, I also want to get the flavor attached to it. See the attached picture please.

I actually got the action log using this novaclient module:

```
    novaclient.v2.instance_action.InstanceAction
```

but it shows me very little details and without the flavor id that I needed. The following fields it shows me are the following:

```
    action, instance_uuid, message, project_id, request_id, start_time and user_id
```

I hope anyone can tell me how to get it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to get the flavor id from the action list / server event list.

Openstack does not keep a database record of what each request did, or a historic record of the instance states.  So you would need to resort to trawling the logs for the request-id ... which is OK for forensics, but does not scale.  (And I don't know if the flavor is in the log messages.)

Of course, you could use the APIs (novaclient, openstacksdk) to get the *current* flavor for the instance, given its instance id.  But that isn't exactly what you want.

---

It is possible record historical information using Gnochi + Ceilometer or similar, but you would need to have set this up already.

Comment: Yeah. The flavor specs is not in the log messages. Thanks for your help.